# Closing Excel Workbook - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, rcw

I've put in the following method that returns a value from an XLS file cell :

```
public static string ReadFromExcel(string filePath, int sheetNum, int xCell, int yCell)
    { 
            List<string> rowValue = new List<string> {};
            var ExcelFilePath = @filePath;

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[sheetNum];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Close(); //<-- here it throws the exception in the title
            xlApp.Quit();

            return xlRange.Cells[xCell, yCell].Value2.ToString();
    }
```

The current code obviously generates an exception because the I close the Workbook and app and then return the value. What's the way to add

```
            xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
```

and still return the value ?

Thanks.

Comment: Capture the return value into a different variable first, and then you should be able to close the Exel app: `var returnValue = xlRange.Cells[xCell, yCell].Value2.ToString(); xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Close(); xlApp.Quit(); return returnValue;`

Comment: Sorry @Rufus I had the exact same thing in mind.

Comment: @JeremyThompson No problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable "returnValue", eg:

```
var returnValue = xlRange.Cells[xCell, yCell].Value2.ToString();
xlApp.ThisWorkbook.Close();
xlApp.Quit();    
return returnValue;
```

**Update**

The error code indicates one of these is the cause:

```
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility: 0xa, Code 0x3ec
# for hex 0x3ec / decimal 1004 :
  INVALID_RESOURCETYPE_LOOKSALIVE                               clusvmsg.h     
  JET_wrnColumnNull                                             esent98.h      
# /* Column is NULL-valued */
  NMERR_BLOB_ENTRY_DOES_NOT_EXIST                               netmon.h       
  SQL_1004_severity_16                                          sql_err        
# Invalid column prefix '%.*ls': No table name specified
  SCEEVENT_ERROR_POLICY_QUEUE                                   uevents.mc     
# Notification of policy change from LSA/SAM failed to be
# added to policy queue.
# %1
  ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS                                           winerror.h     
# Invalid flags.
  EVENT_MAN_PROFILE_NO_FILE_ACCESS                              wlevents.mc    
# The user %1 does not have access to the mandatory profile
# located at %2.
  EVENT_UAE_VERIFICATION_FAILURE                                wlevents2.mc   
# Verification of an automatically enrolled certificate has
# failed. (%1) %2
  WPA_MUST_ACTIVATE_NOW_EVENT                                   wpaevent.mc    
# This copy of Windows must be activated with Microsoft
# before you can continue. To activate Windows, please
# contact a customer service representative.
# 9 matches found for "0x800A03EC"
```

Perhaps your xCell, yCell's aren't in the UsedRange. Can you step through the code "Debug it" and post a screenshot that matches the scenario you're encountering? Thanks.

## Solution

What you're encountering is explained here: [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

To over come it you can use AutoReleaseComObject or the original VSTO-Contrib. Here is some code to show you how to use it:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExcelInterop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"C:\temp\Logfile.CSV";
            int sheetNum = 1;
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            var missing = Type.Missing;
            int xCell = 1, yCell = 1;

            using (AutoReleaseComObject<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application> excelRCWWrapper = new AutoReleaseComObject<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application>(new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()))
            {
                var excelApp = excelRCWWrapper.ComObject;
                var excelAppWkBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
                try
                {
                    using (AutoReleaseComObject<Workbook> excelAppWkBk = new AutoReleaseComObject<Workbook>(excelAppWkBooks.Open(path, false, false, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)))
                    {
                        var workbookComObject = excelAppWkBk.ComObject;
                        Worksheet sheetSource = workbookComObject.Sheets[sheetNum];

                        using (AutoReleaseComObject< Range> excelAppRange = new AutoReleaseComObject<Range>(sheetSource.UsedRange))
                        {
                            returnValue = excelAppRange.ComObject.Cells[xCell, yCell].Value2.ToString();
                        }
                        ReleaseObject(sheetSource);
                        workbookComObject.Close(false);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    excelAppWkBooks.Close();
                    ReleaseObject(excelAppWkBooks);

                    excelRCWWrapper.ComObject.Application.Quit();
                    excelRCWWrapper.ComObject.Quit();
                    ReleaseObject(excelRCWWrapper.ComObject.Application);
                    ReleaseObject(excelRCWWrapper.ComObject);

                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ReleaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj) > 0) ;
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **AutoReleaseComObject** class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExcelInterop
{
    public class AutoReleaseComObject<T> : IDisposable
    {
        private T m_comObject;
        private bool m_armed = true;
        private bool m_disposed = false;

        public AutoReleaseComObject(T comObject)
        {
            Debug.Assert(comObject != null);
            m_comObject = comObject;
        }

#if DEBUG
        ~AutoReleaseComObject()
        {
            // We should have been disposed using Dispose().
            Debug.WriteLine("Finalize being called, should have been disposed");

            if (this.ComObject != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ComObject was not null:{0}, name:{1}.", this.ComObject, this.ComObjectName));
            }

            //Debug.Assert(false);
        }
#endif

        public T ComObject
        {
            get
            {
                Debug.Assert(!m_disposed);
                return m_comObject;
            }
        }

        private string ComObjectName
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ComObject is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
                {
                    return ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)this.ComObject).Name;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        public void Disarm()
        {
            Debug.Assert(!m_disposed);
            m_armed = false;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
#if DEBUG
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
#endif
        }

        #endregion

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!m_disposed)
            {
                if (m_armed)
                {
                    int refcnt = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        refcnt = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_comObject);
                    } while (refcnt > 0);

                    m_comObject = default(T);
                }

                m_disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot showing you I got it working!!

[image]

Comment: Is that the error message you haven't shown me? The new guide to how to ask a question is pretty specific, it's not hard to paste in the error message and you can be assured that's what people will put in a search engine to find this thread.

Comment: Sorry, yea this is the exception: Message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: The thing is, this exception does show in the 'original' code arrangement..

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/470089/Exception-from-HRESULT-0x800A03EC-Error I'm indeed using Excel 2010..

Comment: That's the call I'm making to the above method: Console.WriteLine(Helpers_Generic.ReadFromExcel(@"C:\test.xlsx", 1, 1, 1, driver));

Comment: The value I'm retrieving resides on sheet 1 under A1 location

Comment: OK Fine, I will attempt to reproduce it. You've thoroughly debugged it? And there is no differences like the unused `IWebDriver`? This will break when I first try it?

Comment: Got the same exception without the driver. The driver is there in case the session needs to be picked up. Not relevant to the error at all. So you may take the driver out.

Comment: See my update with the solution and be sure to go through that link I referenced. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks for your help !